# Obj-c Shuffle Array without duplicate

Tags: objective-c, iphone, arrays, xcode

I'm going crazy about this.. Im trying to shuffle an array from a .txt document. But also never repeat the output. If the rows is 0, do alert or smth

I currently have this code, and I just can't figure out how to make it count and remove the presented object from the array. Checked a lot of posts and tried but no success..

```
// declare randomStory as int
int randomStory;

// declare storyString as string
NSString *storyString;

// create variables for text file

// get chronices from text file name
NSString *title = @"chronicles";
// attribute name
NSString *type = @"txt";
// seperation
NSString *separation = @"____________________________________________";
// encoding and variable
NSString *fileText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:title ofType:type] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// create array with seperated text by \n
NSMutableArray *storyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[fileText componentsSeparatedByString:separation]];

// randomize one text from the text file
randomStory = arc4random()%[storyArray count];

storyString = [storyArray objectAtIndex: randomStory];

// output in storyLabel textView
_storyLabel.text
= storyString;

EDIT:
```

Gods sake, cant paste code. Here's how it looks atm, and SIGABRT errors.
http://pastebin.com/21hvrzwU

Comment: How about `[storyArray removeObjectAtIndex:randomStory]` ??

Comment: Could work. But what about when there are no left?

Comment: The code needs to guard against that.  The line before will be a modulo 0.

Comment: Oh.  Can you post the context of this?  Is this all done in the same method?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is (if the OP code resides all in a single method) each call to that method rebuilds a new array from the file.  It would be better to reorganize this way:

1. factor out the file reading to it's own method that's called once
2. build an NSArray shuffler that also runs just once
3. use the shuffled array however you need it in a loop

.

```
- (NSArray *)arrayFromFile {
    NSString *title = @"chronicles";
    NSString *type = @"txt";
    NSString *separation = @"____________________________________________";
    NSString *fileText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:title ofType:type] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    return [fileText componentsSeparatedByString:separation];
}

- (NSArray *)shuffledArray:(NSArray *)array {
    NSMutableArray *mutable = [array mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *result = [@[] mutableCopy];
    while ([mutable count]) {
        NSInteger index = arc4random()%[mutable count];
        [result addObject:mutable[index]];
        [mutable removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
    return result;
}

// not sure the context here, but ....
NSArray *array = [self arrayFromFile];
NSArray *shuffled = [self shuffledArray:array];
for (NSString *string in shuffled) {
    // string will be random here
}
```

**EDIT**

Now, with a little more context, here's how to have the user see a random string in a `UILabel`, when a button is pressed:

Add an array property and a current index to the view controller that contains the button and the label:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *shuffledStrings;
@property(assign,nonatomic) NSInteger currentIndex;
```

Create a "lazy" initializer for the array, using the code I suggested above:

```
- (NSArray *)shuffledStrings {
    if (!_shuffledStrings) {
        NSArray *array = [self arrayFromFile];
        _shuffledStrings = [self shuffledArray:array];
    }
    return _shuffledStrings;
}
```

The OP doesn't define what should happen when the strings from the file have all been presented.  With the tools above, we can just start over with the same shuffled list, or shuffle again and start over...

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.currentIndex == [self.shuffledStrings count]) {
        // just start again
        self.currentIndex = 0;

        // OR, reshuffle and start again
        // self.shuffledStrings = [self shuffledArray:self.shuffledStrings];
        // self.currentIndex = 0;
    }
    NSString *nextString = self.shuffledStrings[self.currentIndex++];
    // assuming you have a myLabel outlet
    self.myLabel.text = nextString;
}
```

Comment: Totally agree on the create a method that would return a new array with the value shuffled! I would have make it a category of NSArray for the sake of reusability thought :)

Comment: The code is logically correct. I guess i'll call the methods by using the for loop in my action button?

Comment: @JimmieMagnusson, Probably, but I can't say for sure without seeing more context.  e.g. what the button's action method is, what the functional requirement is when user pushes the button.

Comment: Basically when the user clicks on a button, a Random text from a text file will appear, nothing more. Also the issue is where the random text should NOT be repeated.

Comment: @JimmieMagnusson, OK.  Please see edit.   I assumed you mean by "appear" that you'd like the string to be presented in a UILabel.

Comment: @JimmieMagnusson - I implemented the code above (faked the file parse and just returned a literal array of strings).  Discovered a bug in my answer which I fixed just now in an edit.  The `shuffledArray:` method should return the variable called **result** not the variable called mutable, which is just there as scratch space.  Sorry about that.  The rest of it works.

Comment: @JimmieMagnusson, you bet.  mark it correct when you get the chance.  also, check out tutorials online or apple docs on using the Xcode debugger.  it's gotten me out of plenty of jams, including finding my error on this one.